# Magento 2 Failing to migrate from domain to local server

Tags: magento2.2

I'm trying to migrate my magento 2 from a domain to my local server, but i'm having some weird error. I alrealy follow a lot of instructions but still got nothing.

Ubunut server 16.04
Magento 2.2.0

Working:
- Website main page, loads and workes properly.

Not Working:
- Admin page says not found and there is no errors on the apache error.log
- Any other location on the website other than the main page, without any error on the error.log.

Note: I do have some "caught SIGTERM, shutting down".

Comment: Please check admin name in app/etc/env.php, might be you are calling wrong url, also please paste screen shot of your issue. Including url you are calling.

Comment: Thank you for answering.The information was already checked on the env.php.
[link](https://imgur.com/a/3vQoa) 
The second image happens when i click on the "QUEM SOMOS" on the menu.

Comment: It seems there is an issue with url rewrite, please check with putting index.php after host name and also keep backup of url rewrite. Then empty that table and reindex again to generate url. It might help.

Comment: Ok, i'm noob with magento. But what you u mean with backup Url Rewrite. For my knowledge it seems like all pages are store on the database, but as urls do go from clicking "QUEM SOMOS" the client is requesting an website inside the folder "quem-somos" wich doesn't exist. I fell like is something very easy, and i'm being very dumb.
Thank you for answering.